# GIMP CLI Batch script errors

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, plugins, gimp

I am trying to liquid rescale pictures dynamically with [GIMP Liquid Rescale Plugin](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/).

I am doing this on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS using the following command:

```
gimp -i -f -b "(batch-gimp-lqr-full "/var/www/liquid/uploads/feelsBadMan_2.png" "/var/www/liquid/distorts/feelsBadMan.png" 400 400 "" "" 1000 "" 1000 150 "" 7 150.0 TRUE TRUE 0 FALSE 3 0 0 FALSE 0 TRUE)" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"
```

Using this on my Windows system is working fine (changing the strings of the in- and output file of course.)

On Ubuntu, I get the following error messages:

```
(gimp:26440): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GeglConfig' has no property named 'cache-size'

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C64A60 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C63D30 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:behind-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C64130 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:multiply-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C64540 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:screen-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C65A10 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:overlay-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C65E50 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:difference-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C66220 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:addition-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C66670 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:subtract-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C66A70 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:darken-only-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C66EA0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:lighten-only-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C672D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hue-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C67610 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:saturation-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C67A50 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C68420 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:value-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C68650 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:divide-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C68AE0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dodge-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C68EA0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:burn-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C692D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hardlight-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C69740 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:softlight-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C69B20 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-extract-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C69F70 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-merge-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C6A320 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C6A6D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C6AB40 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"

(gimp:26440): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1C6AEF0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: ( : 1) eval: unbound variable: /var/www/liquid/uploads/feelsBadMan_2.png
```

Anybody know where to start solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem.

I had to escape the quote marks in the argument, i.e. replace `"` with `\"`, to prevent the shell removing them before they were passed to GIMP.

Works like a charm. Thanks everybody for reading.